# inline center three image

Tags: html, css

In my header I have three logos. I need to center those logoes, where there is a margin between them on around 100 - 140px. I did not know how to do that, so I solved it with putting a margin on 150px, with the result that the logos are not placed on mobile devices.

[image: How the logos should look like]

On the mobile they should be vertical instead of horizontal.

I actually thought I could do it like this:

display: inline;
margin: 0 auto;

But that is not doing abything at all. Does anybody knows how I can solve this, so they also fit on mobile devices?

```
   <div class="fullscreen landing parallax">
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 logo">
                        <!-- /.logo -->
                        <img src="/img/seminar/company_1-logo-white-small.png" alt="company_1" class="logo">
                        <img src="/img/seminar/company_2-white.png" alt="company_2">
                        <img src="/img/seminar/company_3-white.png" alt="company_3">
                    </div>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.logo {
    margin: 20px 0 15px 0;

}
.logo img{
    margin-left: 160px;
    width: 163px; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to separate the ***row into 3 columns*** and place the ***images inside the column*** with ***bootstrap's text-center*** class. Bootstrap will align images vertically on mobile UI.

**On iPad horizotal**
[image]

**On iPad vertical**
[image]

**On desktop browser**
[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <style type="text/css">
    .logo {
      margin: 20px 0 15px 0;
    }
    .logo img {
      margin-left: 160px;
      width: 163px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="fullscreen landing parallax">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
            <img src="http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/mrmen/images/5/52/Small.gif/revision/latest?cb=20100731114437" alt="company_1" class="logo">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
            <img src="http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/mrmen/images/5/52/Small.gif/revision/latest?cb=20100731114437" alt="company_1" class="logo">

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
            <img src="http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/mrmen/images/5/52/Small.gif/revision/latest?cb=20100731114437" alt="company_1" class="logo">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. That is exact what I would like on the mobile device menu. But I do not quite understand how it should function on the desktop with this?

Comment: perfect. That is exact what I am looking for. This fits the mobile and the desktop view. Thank you a lot.

Comment: I'm glad it helped ;)

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
.logo {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
}
```

You'll probably need to set a width on the `.logo` element and maybe `margin:0 auto;'  too depending on its width.

For more info on flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

**Live example:**

```css
.logo {
 display:flex;
 justify-content:center;
 align-items:center;
}

.logo img {
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
 <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/100" alt="">
 <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/100" alt="">
 <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/100" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. I can see that it is actually working. But how would be the best way to set a margin between the pictures?

Comment: I edited the answer, just add `margin` to the images.

Comment: That make sence. Thank you a lot. Just one last thing if you have time. If I look at the mobile view they are not fitting still. I tried to add: `/* iPhone 4/5 (portrait) ----------- */
@media (max-width: 320px) {
 .logo {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 10px;
     
 }`

But it is really not doing so much. Would you have an idea how I should do it here? I can see it is on almost every device they are aligned right

Comment: Maybe they are too big. Without being able to take a look at your codebase I can't tell. Also, you're using Bootstrap, so that's most likely getting in the way too. I would appreciate it if you accept the answer by the way.